# Will my Blu-ray drive be able to read a 4K Blu-ray disk?

Tags: blu-ray

I have bought an ASUS BC-12D2HT Blu-ray drive for my rarely used Windows 10 computer connected to my TV.  To my understanding, the new 4K UHD Blu-ray format stores more data on the disk, and many Blu-ray players will not be able to play the new disks.

Given that the specifications for the drive says it can read the following formats, will I be able to play the new disks?

- CD-ROM
- CD-R
- CD-RW
- DVD-ROM
- DVD-R
- DVD-RAM
- DVD-RW
- DVD+RW
- DVD+R
- DVD+R DL
- DVD-R DL
- BD-R
- BD-R DL
- BD-RE
- BD-RE DL
- BD-ROM
- BD-ROM DL
- BD-R QL
- BD-R TL
- BD-RE TL
- BD-R LTH
- DVD-ROM DL

Comment: It must support UHD BluRay so no, yours doesn't mention it.

Comment: @MichaelBay Thanks.  I was expecting this to be the case.  It is a very interesting experiment - I thought that Bluray would be the last incompatible format to the previous technologies that users accepted widespread ("Please go buy new stuff") before streaming completely took over.  Now I get to see if that assumption is true.